# Is it possible to obtain the classes or methods of other class with out adding a reference of that class

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my project i am having 2 class libraries namely `DAL` and `BAL` . While adding reference only one reference is added and for the other i am getting some `Circular Dependancy` error. So is there any possibility to obtain the members of other class with out adding reference of that class.

Answer (score 0):

A circular dependency usually means there is a design flaw in your system. If there is some common functionality that both libraries need then perhaps extract that into a third assembly and reference that from both.

Alternatively, you could have a third project that references the other two and is responsible for handling communication between them, a mediator.

Comment: So as per your answer i would like to create another `class library` and have to access from that